# I'm trying to fetch the bot's permissions to check if the command will be able to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch the bot's permissions to check if the command will be able to run. I have the following code:

```js
let botid = "idbot"
let bot = client.users.cache.get(botid)
if (!bot.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) 
  return message.channel.send("Para mim poder liberar a função de registro eu preciso da permissão **Administrador**, por favor peça para algum **Staff** do servidor configurar, Obrigado.")
```

I receive the following error:

```
if (!bot.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot` is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) and `User`s don't have `permissions`, only `GuildMember`s do. For this, you'll need to grab the `Guild` (either by getting by its ID, or just using `message.guild`). [`guild#me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) will be your bot as a `GuildMember` of that guild.

You could also just use the [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method on `guild.members`. Anyway, you'll need a `guild` to check your bot's permissions.

```js
let botid = 'idbot';
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID');
// OR get it from the message
let { guild } = message;

let bot = guild.me;
// OR fetch it from members
let bot = await guild.members.fetch(botid);

if (!bot.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR'))
  return message.channel.send(
    'Para mim poder liberar a função de registro eu preciso da permissão **Administrador**, por favor peça para algum **Staff** do servidor configurar, Obrigado.',
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `bot` as you defined it is just a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), meaning it just has informations like it's tag, username, servers it is in etc.. what you want is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), it's the same person but on a specific server, it has roles, a hoist color and [`permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions) which is what you're searching for :

```js
let bot = message.guild.me; // The bot's GuildMember object
if (!bot.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply('I am not an admin!')
```